# How to mark checkbox as selected using Bitwise in CakePHP?

Tags: arrays, cakephp, checkbox, bit-manipulation, selected

I am developing an application in CakePHP 2.6 and I have a form where a user can set a series of flags when creating a calendar event.

I have managed to set up the 'add' action to display the flags and to also loop through in the controller after validation and save the value into my table. This process is done using bitwise. Code example below:

'add' action view:

`echo $this->Form->input('flag', array('label' => false, 'type' => 'select', 'multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $flagtypes, 'hiddenField' => false));`

'add' action controller:

```
$flags = 0;
foreach ($data['flag'] as $r) {
    $flags |= (int)$r;
}
```

**I am however having trouble getting the checkboxes for the flags to be marked as selected in the edit action view when they are displayed.**

'edit' action view:

```
$selected = array($results[0]['BitwiseFlag']);
echo $this->Form->input('flag', array('label' => false, 'type' => 'select', 'multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $flagtypes, 'hiddenField' => false, 'selected' => $selected));
```

$results[0]['BitwiseFlag'] = 32 in the table.

$flagtypes array:

`array(2) { [32]=> string(4) "Test" [64]=> string(9) "Testing 2" }`

Comment: You might want to look into [Bitmasked Behavior](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/2.x/Model/Behavior/BitmaskedBehavior.php) and the [article](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/26/bitmasked-using-bitmasks-in-cakephp/) to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fully sure what your forms data structure looks like, but you should be able to set the flags from within your controller. Set the relevant values in `$this->request->data`, something like this:-

```
$this->request->data[$this->{$this->modelClass}->alias]['flag'] = [
    0 => true,
    1 => false,
    2 => true
];
```

Then when you use `$this->Form->input('flag', [...])` it should check the correct flags for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your input line to this :

```
$selected = array($results[0]['BitwiseFlag']);

// Change 'checked' to 'selected'.
echo $this->Form->input('flag', array('label' => false, 'type' => 'select', 'multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $flagtypes, 'hiddenField' => false, 'selected' => $selected));
```

Comment: Tried this suggestion and checkboxes still aren't showing as selected. I have updated the view code in my original post.

Comment: What if you pass the value to $selected array like `$selected = array($flagtypes[$results[0]['BitwiseFlag']])` ?

Comment: Still no luck sadly. Would `$results[0]['BitwiseFlag']` need to be broken down from int into the bits?